# Rails Engine проблема интеграции с gem draper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В `Rails Engine` приложении необходимо подключить [gem draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper). После выполнения всех инструкций по докам, а именно:

После установки гема и выполнения команды `rails generate decorator` создаю декоратор:

```
class OrderDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  delegate :hide_part_number, :expiration_date, to: :credit_card, prefix: true

  decorates_association :credit_card
  decorates_association :shipping_address
  decorates_association :billing_address
  decorates_association :order_items

end
```

При запуске приложения разит ошибку [image: Скриншот ошибки]

**Мой engine_name.gemspec.rb**

```
s.add_dependency "rails", "~> 5.0.0", ">= 5.0.0.1"
  s.add_dependency 'aasm', '~> 4.10', '>= 4.10.1'
  s.add_dependency 'wicked', '~> 1.3'
  s.add_dependency 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
  s.add_dependency 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'
  s.add_dependency 'draper', '~> 2.1'
  s.add_dependency 'activesupport-decorators', '~> 1.0'

  s.add_development_dependency 'pg'
```

На одном из сайтов нашел совет как побороть эту проблему, но к сожалению не помогло:

Там советую добавить в engine.rb

```
config.to_prepare do
      Dir.glob(Rails.root + 'app/decorators/**/*_decorator*.rb').each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
    end
```

Но это ничего не изменило.

Comment: Берите отладчик, и... выясняйте, есть ли класс декоратора вообще. Загружен ли гем `draper`. Я уже в какой раз вам советую освоить отладчик?..

Comment: Есть подозрение, что у вас `OrderDecorator`, а модель `ShoppingCart::OrderDecorator` и происходит несовпадение, но сказать наверняка вы сможете, только проверив эту теорию.

Comment: Видимо у вас модель `Order` не загружена, если она вообще  должна быть в пространстве `ShoppingCart`, или точнее не та модель загружена. Насколько я понимаю, просто OrderDecorator применяется самочинно только к модели верхнего уровня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В контроллере, когда декорируте коллекцию или объект (например, `@orders`) укажите класс декоратора явно при помощи опции `with`

```
class ShoppingCard::OrdersController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  decorates_assigned :orders, with: OrderDecorator
  ...
```